# How to get source of a sampled bin in Coverage in QuestaSIM

Tags: system-verilog, function-coverage, questasim

I'm using QuestaSIM and have a merged coverage report from regression.

From my merged coverage report, how can I trace a sampled bin back to its simulation (test name & seed value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found out the answer of the question, so here I am posting it.

In QuestaSIM, while merging the coverage a flag can be used for the same purpose.

vcover merge -testassociated

This flag will keep an eye on each test's contribution to the coverage. So after merged coverage report, while opening it in questa, again one flag can be used for getting that, which bins were hit by which tests.

vsim -coverage -cvgbintstamp

So in the coverage report, on any bin, just right click and select "Find Tests that hit". So you will have list of tests, which have hit that particular bin.